# ModelState.Remove a field with virtual that has the same name as an other field in the object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

So the thing is during validation, I have to explicitly remove a field from validation.
I have Operator and Workshop entities
Operator has

```
[Required]
public string Name{ get; set; }
[Required]
public virtual Workshop workshop {get; set;}
```

and in the Workshop entity I have the following

```
[Required]
public string Name{ get; set; }
```

And I want to ignore the required name of the workshop

```
      [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind] Operator operator)
        {
         //Name here will remove the validation on Operator's name, not the workshop name
            ModelState.Remove("Name");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Operateurs.Add(operator);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        ...
       }
```

Comment: `"Workshop.Name"` (but why do you have a `[Required]` attribute if its not required?

Comment: it is required for the entity itself. But in this case it is not. All I need is the ID of the workshop that will be added by EntityFramework. I have one to many relationship between Operator and Workshop. So when adding an Operator I simply need the ID of the Workshop. Thank you very much that worked

Comment: Then, as always, use a view model. You should not use data models in views when editing data.

Comment: Actually it is not really needed here I guess. I only use one Entity (Operator), that has the ID of another entity as a property. I do not need the other entity (Workshop) in any kind. It gets dragged because of the dependency that's why I'm removing it from the validation